# Growth curve modeling using lmer - how is it different from mixed effects regression?

Tags: lme4-nlme, curve-fitting, growth-model

EDIT: I'm realising time cannot be a random effect, is that right? Where does it fit with other fixed effects? Can time be a polynomial?

I am trying to set up a growth curve analysis using lmer, I have used it before for mixed models regression, but as this analysis is more complicated I am struggling with where to start. I don't really understand the difference between the two.

I have RT data from multiple participants, each providing data on 20 trials. Each trial includes 20 time points. I want to see whether the RT increases overtime in a systematic way. I also have multiple continuous predictors to account for changes in RT, but I want to build the basic model with random effects only.

Most tutorials focus on differences between two groups, so I have trouble applying them to my problem. Here is my model:

```
Model0 <- lmer(RT~ 1 + (1|Timepoint/Trial) + (1|Trial/Participant), data=Data, REML=FALSE)

Random effects:
 Groups                     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Participant:Trial   (Intercept) 0.051866 0.22774 
 Trial:Timepoint     (Intercept) 0.002138 0.04624 
 Timepoint           (Intercept) 0.028004 0.16734 
 Trial               (Intercept) 0.002483 0.04983 
 Residual                        0.185963 0.43123 


EDIT: how about this model with timepoint as a polunomial fixed effect nested within trial?
Model0 <- lmer(RT~ 1 + (Timepoint^2/Trial) + (1|Trial/Participant), data=Data, REML=FALSE) 

#this would be a hypothetical model with fixed effects 
Model1 <- lmer(RT~ 1 + A + B + C + D (1|Timepoint/Trial) + (1|Trial/Participant), data=Data, REML=FALSE)
```

As far as I understand, this is a model where variance in RT accounts for Timepoint variation on each Trial, and the Trial variation for each participant. The random effects suggest that not much of the variance is accounted by that, maybe by time a little bit, but nothing much to report just yet.

Here are my questions: Does this account for time already? Do I have to add anything to predictors A through D to indicate how I expect things to change? For example, I think a quadratic function will fit this data, based on the plot below, but I have no idea which variable I should transform and how? And wheat to look for for the results?

[image]

Comment: The design of your experiment is not clear. For example: Do these trials happen sequentially in time, in which cases there are 20 trials x 20 time points = 400 time points per subject? And why are participants nested in Trial when you have the same participants participate in all trials. Your plot is missing axis labels.... In short, consider providing a better description of the data and the design.

Comment: you're right, participants shouldn't be nested in this case. I was a bit clueless about the whole thing when asking the question but I'm now making some progress in understanding so will revisit the question if I have more specific queries